# Accessing imported functions 2 levels deep or more

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a question regarding chaining of imports. Say you have `import {myFunction} from './utils.js'` at the top of your myScript.js file. If that utils.js file had `import {myOtherFunction} from './myLibrary'` does that mean myScript.js file also has access to `myOtherFunction`, or do you have to add that last import statement to the myScript.js file too?

Comment: If `myOtherFunction` is not export it you cannot call it in myScript.js. If it *is* exported, you still need to import it to call it. However, `myOtherFunction` can still be called internally by `myFunction`.

Comment: Ok, so while `myFunction` still gets access to `myOtherFunction`, I need an extra `import {myOtherFunction} from './myLibrary'` at the top of my myScript.js file to get direct access to `myOtherFunction`, yes?

Comment: Correct. To call something, you have to import it.

Comment: Thanks VLAZ. Appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to add a separate import for myOtherFunction in your myScript.js file, just importing myFunction will work.